# Confusing partial template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, boost, type-traits

I saw this piece of code and it's so confusing to me:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

template<class TT, typename Enable = void> struct UU { BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(sizeof(TT) == 0, "undefined UU"); };

template<class TT>
struct UU<
        TT,
        typename boost::enable_if_c<
                !boost::is_same<
                        TT,
                        typename boost::remove_cv<
                                typename boost::decay<TT>::type
                            >::type
                    >::value
                || boost::is_pointer<TT>::value
            >::type
    >
    : UU<
            typename boost::remove_cv<
                typename boost::decay<
                    typename boost::remove_pointer<TT>::type
                >::type
            >::type
        >
{};
```

I know I'm only supposed to ask one question but I'm not sure how to express my confusion using one question only, so my apologies in advance.

I've read about [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), but the template argument of enable_if_c is confusing. Does it mean that if TT is different from the decayed TT or if TT is a pointer, then the partial template specialization exists?

Secondly, what does a struct inheriting from itself mean? In this case, UU is inheriting from UU (itself)? Is this some kind of recursive templating?

(The code compiles with no errors.)

Comment: Specialization will be selected when `enable_if_c` condition is true. `UU` does not inherit from itself, it inherits from a different specialization of the same template.

Comment: If the code actually used the names `UU` and `TT` that is the real problem. If you just removed the real names it for the purpose of asking on [SO] that is... unforgiveable. Code is for humans to read. Don't be surprised that code is unintelligible when stripped of semantic cues (ask reverse engineers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand now. Here's a sample simulation:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template<class TT, typename Enable = void> struct UU { BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(sizeof(TT) == 0, "undefined UU"); };

template<class TT>
struct UU<
        TT,
        typename boost::enable_if_c<
                !boost::is_same<
                        TT,
                        typename boost::remove_cv<
                                typename boost::decay<TT>::type
                            >::type
                    >::value
                || boost::is_pointer<TT>::value
            >::type
    >
    : UU<
            typename boost::remove_cv<
                typename boost::decay<
                    typename boost::remove_pointer<TT>::type
                >::type
            >::type
        >
{
    UU()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

struct dummy
{
    dummy()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; 
    }
};

template<>
struct UU<dummy>
{
    UU()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef dummy**& mytype;
    std::cout << typeid(typename boost::remove_cv<typename boost::decay<mytype>::type>::type).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::is_pointer<mytype>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::is_same<mytype, typename boost::remove_cv<typename boost::decay<mytype>::type>::type>::value << std::endl;

    UU<mytype> uu;
    return 0;
}
```

When run:

```
me@ub16:~/tmp/traits$ g++ -I~/me/bin/boost_1_60_0 c.cpp && ./a.out
PP5dummy
0
0
UU<dummy>::UU()
UU<TT, typename boost::enable_if_c<((! boost::is_same<TT, typename boost::remove_cv<typename boost::decay<T>::type>::type>::value) || boost::is_pointer<T>::value)>::type>::UU() [with TT = dummy*; typename boost::enable_if_c<((! boost::is_same<TT, typename boost::remove_cv<typename boost::decay<T>::type>::type>::value) || boost::is_pointer<T>::value)>::type = void]
UU<TT, typename boost::enable_if_c<((! boost::is_same<TT, typename boost::remove_cv<typename boost::decay<T>::type>::type>::value) || boost::is_pointer<T>::value)>::type>::UU() [with TT = dummy**; typename boost::enable_if_c<((! boost::is_same<TT, typename boost::remove_cv<typename boost::decay<T>::type>::type>::value) || boost::is_pointer<T>::value)>::type = void]
UU<TT, typename boost::enable_if_c<((! boost::is_same<TT, typename boost::remove_cv<typename boost::decay<T>::type>::type>::value) || boost::is_pointer<T>::value)>::type>::UU() [with TT = dummy**&; typename boost::enable_if_c<((! boost::is_same<TT, typename boost::remove_cv<typename boost::decay<T>::type>::type>::value) || boost::is_pointer<T>::value)>::type = void]
me@ub16:~/tmp/traits$
```

When `UU<dummy**&>` is instantiated, the compiler tries to create/define `struct UU<dummy**>`. Then it tries to create `struct UU<dummy*>`. Finally, it creates `struct UU<dummy>`.

When the partial template specialization, `struct UU<dummy>`, is not defined, the static assertion of the primary template fails:

```
me@ub16:~/tmp/traits$ g++ -I~/me/bin/boost_1_60_0 c.cpp && ./a.out
In file included from c.cpp:1:0:
c.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct UU<dummy, void>’:
c.cpp:10:8:   recursively required from ‘struct UU<dummy**, void>’
c.cpp:10:8:   required from ‘struct UU<dummy**&>’
c.cpp:62:13:   required from here
c.cpp:7:56: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’
 template<class TT, typename Enable = void> struct UU { BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(sizeof(TT) == 0, "undefined UU"); };
```

In essence, the author of the code wants other developers who will use his/her code to define the partial template specialization, `template<> struct UU<TT>`, for each TT to be used.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean that if TT is different from the decayed TT or if TT is a pointer, then the partial template specialization exists?

Exactly. Otherwise there's a substitution failure, and the primary template is used for the type argument `TT` that you pass in.

> Secondly, what does a struct inheriting from itself mean? In this case, UU is inheriting from UU (itself)? Is this some kind of recursive templating?

It doesn't inherit from itself, it inherits from another instantiation of the class template. It's not *really* recursive because that other instantiation is created by passing another, modified, type into it. Though if you consider templates to be meta-functions that operate on types, then that is indeed a recursive invocation. Very similar to what you'll see in functional programming.

The idea is to reduce a composite type into the type it is composed of. So a reference to the referred type, an array to the array element type, and a pointer to the pointee type. The inheritance allows the process to continue until we don't have a composite type on our hands.

Eventually, the primary template checks the reduced type for correctness (in this case, having a non-zero size).

Comment: "*the primary template checks the reduced type for correctness (in this case, having a non-zero size)*" - what would be an *incorrect* type? And isn't sizeof in C++ always >0?

Comment: @RustyX - In standard C++, always. But extensions do exist, and some pathological cases can make classes with `sizeof` 0. Like sehe pointed out, the OP has chosen some very poor names for the template and its parameter. I have no idea where an actual template like that may be in use, but it's not inconceivable it's meant to catch those nasty surprises.

Answer (score 0):

It inherits from UU but the instantiation is different (think for instance if the type passed were int * const *, it would still be a pointer even after the first level of pointer and cv were removed). It does, however, make sure that void ** isn't passed (because a void parameter will eventually trigger the main form with the static assert).